# xrandr can't open display

Tags: display

I have a new Ubuntu Server 18.04 installed on a Toshiba Radius laptop, a usb switch (kvm) between the laptop and the Plugable 3.0. When I run xrandr  the first message is "Can't Open Display". I am running Ubuntu in text mode, no graphical interface at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am trying to see if my external monitor is even recognized using xrandr --listproviders, but still getting the  "Can't Open Display" message

Comment: Run export DISPLAY=:0 if you get this message, "can't open display" – (source [Jeroen Kransen](https://askubuntu.com/users/41956/jeroen-kransen) Feb 20 '15 at 12:13

Comment: ➜  ~ export DISPLAY=:0
➜  ~ xrandr --listproviders     
No protocol specified
Can't open display :0